# APK file installs when directly build, but not when creating an .apk file by using distribution procedure (Titanium Studio)

Tags: android, titanium, apk

I am working on an android application in Titanium. When i do a direct build by clicking `Run>Android Emulator`, the size of `app.apk` file generated under `"approot/build/android/build"` is **8 MB** and i could able to copy this file in my device and install.

But when i package and distribute for Android store by choosing **Keystore and password**, the **resultant .apk file size is only 5MB** and when i copy this directly to device and try to install. Its actually not getting installed.

Will the app built using distribution process will be this size? please suggest.

**Output from adb when installing the app :**

Click on this link to see the output bigger : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dtzb7.png

[image]

Comment: Could you post the logcat from the failed install? It might be due to different application signatures between debug and release.

Comment: Also, the different sizes is reasonable.

Comment: Are you enabling proguard ? the size difference may be caused by optimization witch cause the signed apk running.

Comment: @Steelight I copied the projectname.apk file into device and clicked install option.. the screen showed like `Application Not Installed` in the device.. i am not sure how i should get the log from mobile..

if this is due to different application signature between debug and release.. how do i resolve this?

Comment: @Anis No. i am not enabling Proguard, yes its logical that the signed apk file has reduced size.
But i can be sure that the application is working when it runs in my device.. then only i can post it to Google play...

Comment: Can you post or mail your signed apk file.

Comment: Actually i cannot share the apk file, due to some restriction..

Comment: Try uninstalling the debug version before installing the release one. Also try connect through ADB and run "adb logcat" just before installing, and copy the output here.

Comment: @Steelight I have updated the question with output from adb..
it returns installation error code 103 and says no certificates at entry.... please see the question for output..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, below are the answer to my question

1) Yes, when app is executed for production the file size will be reduced.

2) After publishing the app to a specific folder, we should be signing the application using below
   command

`jarsigner -verbose -keystore /home/balan/tmp/KeyStore360/android.keystore myproject.apk androidalias`

Thanks for Steelight letting me know about the `adb logcat`, this helped me to sort out that my apk file missing certificate.

Answer (score 3):

Googling, I found this for error code 103:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rhomobile/WJJvB8NVcuU

Could it be that you are using sdk 1.7? try to switch to the java sdk 1.6.

Comment: +1 Thanks for continuous help Steelight..
the adb helped me to sort out the issue..